# Windows 10 no longer detects new audio port connections after replacing GPU

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I just upgraded my GPU to a 3060 ti.

When I booted my computer, the sound was working normally and the drivers were out of date.

I updated to the latest driver through the GeForce Experience control panel and the video settings seem to be working as intended.

However, I have both a pair of speakers and a pair of headphones connected to my computer through 2 seperate back audio jacks.

Before the update, sound would play out of both of them when the speakers were selected in the audio setting, and each time I plugged in a new connection to an audio jack, the realtek sound manager would pop up and set it up.

After the update, sound only plays out of the speakers, and only if they're connected to specific ports that worked before the update - trying to connect them to a different port doesn't work, and when the speakers are on there is no way to hear sound out of the headphones. Also, the realtek sound manager no longer pops up upon connecting new audio devices.

I tried going to the sound manager, and only the speakers were recognized as a sound device. If they were connected to a different port, they would appear on the list of sound devices but not make any sound.

I came across [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/no-sound-after-updating-graphics-drivers/50663d0b-e3d3-44cd-b004-60e26eefa0f6) and tried the solutions that made sense: The sound driver is up to date, windows audio service is running, the troubleshooter didn't detect a problem, sound settings don't help since the headphones aren't recognized as a sound device, IDT High Definition Audio CODEC is not installed.

Has anyone faced this issue? Is there a way to get the realtek sound manager back / get the computer to recognize new audio connections again?

Answer (score -1):

Download and install [Display Driver Uninstaller](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html). This software is designed to remove all traces of NVIDIA Drivers including left over registry items. Be sure to choose NVIDIA GPU from the drop down and go with the recommended settings to clean out the driver and reboot.

Now when you're back on your desktop, launch your NVIDIA Driver installer once more, this time head over to "Custom" installation and **untick** HD Audio Driver in the list of drivers that are going to be installed. Even though you used DDU to clean out the driver, it doesn't hurt to also tick "Perform Clean Installation" here either.

[image]

Proceed through the installer as usual. If necessary, be sure to uninstall/re-install your built-in audio drivers after doing this. Has this solved your audio problem?

Comment: No, the problem hasn't changed after doing those steps.
It actually made things worse since now my computer is also not detecting my second monitor

Comment: The DDU will remove all traces so this will bring you down to only one monitor until you re-install the NVIDIA driver. Have you re-installed the NVIDIA driver yet?

Comment: Yes. To be more specific the computer doesn't detect the second monitor 90% of the time. It went from detecting it before using DDU, to sporadically jumping between detecting it and not detecting it and constantly resetting the resolution settings, to not detecting it at all.

Comment: and is this the latest driver from the NVIDIA website?

Comment: Yes. Oh and also it's monitor-specific. I have a smaller monitor that works fine.
edit: just installed the driver for the monitor model and it's working again, so that's on me. Sorry for not thinking about it earlier

Comment: Ok, so the monitors have not been impacted by the steps above. Has the audio situation changed?

Comment: No. Still need to replace the connection at the audio jack to switch between headphones and speakers